# How to configure programmatically a unique constraint on several fields of a custom entity?

Tags: 8, entities, console

How could I configure a unique constraint on several  fields of a custom entity I have already created with drupalconsole.

The purpose is not allowing insert of two record of the same entity having for example same lastname and fisrtname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by elstevenson, I used the validation API.

Here the steps.

1. Create a repository in your module repo. 
   /src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint
2. Create a constraint (name = Unique)

   ```
   namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

   /**
   * @Constraint(
   *   id = "Unique",
   *   label = @Translation("Unique ", context = "Validation"),
   *   type = "entity:entity_name"`
   * )
   */


   class UniqueConstraint extends Constraint {
      public $message= 'Unique entity!';
      }
   ```
3. Create a constraintValidator, and we populate the validate method with an entity query to make sure that there is no record having the same value of field1 and field 2:

   ```
    namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

   class UniqueConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint) {
    $field1 = $entity->field1->value;
    $field2 = $entity->field2->value;
    $entity_type_id = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $value_taken = (bool) \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)
     ->condition('field1',  $field1)
     ->condition('field2',  $field2)
     ->range(0, 1)
     ->count()
     ->execute();
   if ($value_taken)
   {
   $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);

   }
   ```

   }
     }
4. Then configure our constraint in our entity (annotations part):

/**

```
* Defines the entity_name entity.

*

    * @ingroup entity_name
    *
    * @ContentEntityType(
    *   id = "entity_name",
    *   label = @Translation("entity_name"),
    *   handlers = {
    *     ...
    *     "form" = {
    *     ..
    *     },
    *  ....
    *  
    *   constraints = {
    *     "Unique" = {}
    *   }
    * )
    */
```

4. Then you should uninstall your module and then reinstall it . (if your entity is populated with data, you have to delete all the date).
5. In your code (for example in your form) , you have to ensure the validation :

   ```
   $violations = $entity->validate();
   if ($violations->count() > 0) 
   {
    $violation = $violations[0];

    drupal_set_message($violation->getMessage(),'warning');
   }
   ```

Hope it will help.

Comment: For french people, all these steps are explained in this article in french  [link] (https://mydrupalworld.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/entity-validation-api-cas-pratique/)

Comment: We can't use Symfony's native UniqueEntity constraint http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html because Drupal doesn't actually use Symfony validation constraints. Here's a list of constraints implemented in Drupal core validation API:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21validator%21ConstraintValidator.php/class/uses/ConstraintValidator/8.2.x

Answer (score 1):

I asked something similar a little while ago: [How do I do a 'required if other field = x' using the entity validation api?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215068/how-do-i-do-a-required-if-other-field-x-using-the-entity-validation-api)

Basically, you want to use the Entity Validation API to create a Validation Plugin for your form.

Comment: thanks, but my need is a validating in database insert. It's basically adding a constraint unique in databse

Comment: Yes. What you'd want to do it what I described in my own answer to the question (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/215280/66405), ie create an Validation Plugin for your entity. If you go into the Comment module in core modules, there's a check against database content in that. There's some more notes on what I did in the answer I linked to.