# Custom entity field validation using constraint

Tags: entities

I have custom entity (component) with two fields field_area_type and field_dd_test_data. I want to add custom validation to make sure that user must enter either of two fields. I have used ConstraintValidator as suggested in different blogs.
https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-5/issue-2/introducing-drupal-8s-en...

I am able to validate for one field, means in validate function I get only value of one field. How can I get values of both field in validate function of ConstraintValidator? Please help me

Comment: You need to add a validation to the custom entity, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215508/how-to-configure-programmatically-a-unique-constraint-on-several-fields-of-a-cus

Comment: I have used as mentioned in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215508/how-to-configure-programmatically-a-unique-constraint-on-several-fields-of-a-cus. But on validation, error border line added to all fields in that component entity. I just want to compare two fields in that entity and show error message to any of these two fields. thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to generate more user friendly error messages the Form API might be a better place, add a custom validation function to the entity form. Keep the validation on the entity level, because there might be incorrect data coming from other code than a form that you want to catch.

Comment: Finally I am able to make it work using validation constraint in one case. While validating two fields 
$field1 = $entity->field_optional_image_headline->value;
$field2 = $entity->field_optional_image_caption->value;
Case 1 : Working 
if($field1 != $field2) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->messageRequired)
          ->atPath('field_optional_image_headline')
          ->addViolation();
    }
Case 2 :  Modified condition :- not working
if($field1 == '' && $field2 != '') { //added same viloation }

Comment: thanks for help. it worked for me. added conditon if(isset($entity->field_optional_image_headline))